# What is the correct LANGUAGE_CODE for the UK?

Tags: django, django-templates

Is the correct `LANGUAGE_CODE` for British English `'en-GB'` or `'en-gb'` when using [I18N](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#language-code)?

Does it make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the definition of [language code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/#term-language-code) given in the Django Docs:

> **language code**
> Represents the name of a language. Browsers send the names of the languages they accept in the `Accept-Language` HTTP header using this format. Examples: `it`, `de-at`, `es`, `pt-br`. **Language codes are generally represented in lowercase, but the HTTP `Accept-Language` header is case-insensitive.** The separator is a dash.

Emphasis mine. Either capitalization is accepted, but the lowercase form is more typical.

Comment: Thanks, the list of language identifiers referred to in the Django docs is uppercase... http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html ?

Comment: @alias51 Indeed, and the RFC linked in the first sentence of that page says "All tags are to be treated as case insensitive; there exists conventions for capitalization of some of them, but these should not be taken to carry meaning."

Answer (score 0):

it is more likely to be `en-gb` for the uk

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).